# Extract value from vector of map in scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a vector of map.

```
Vector(Map(value1 -> 1, value2 -> 2))
```

I want to extract the value form map of vector. I want the value of value1 so my result should be 1. How to do it in the most efficient way?

Comment: What happens if you have multiple maps with the same key? The first one? What have you tried?

Comment: It's not the case with multiple maps.I have tried:

val answer =  vector.map
    {
      result => result("value1")
    }

    println(answer)

It gives me Vector(1), i just want 1.

Comment: I dot not understand, what do you mean the vector doesn't have multiple maps? If it is a vector of just one element, why do you have a vector in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

You should guard against the value you are searching for not existing

```
val value1 = ???
val value2 = ???

val vector = Vector(Map(value1 -> 1, value2 -> 2))

val searchVal = value1

// Returns an Option[Int] if found else None

vector.find(m => m.contains(searchVal)).map(m => m(searchVal))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the first value, you can try:

```
vector.collectFirst
{
  case map if map.keySet.contains("value") => map("value")
}
```